# how to inspect time and and reduce I\O in Postgresql for each?

Tags: java, postgresql, io, operation

How to find number of operation happening at Database and the time for each associated operation for each PostgreSQL query ?

Comment: This would be a better question if you explained in a bit more detail what you're trying to accomplish.